# Error creating a temp file using NSTemporaryDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c

In IOS 9.1 there's apparently a problem with the following code. What am I doing wrong?

```
NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foobar.dat"];
NSString *s = @"testing";
NSData *data = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL ok = [data writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
if(!ok) {
    NSLog(@"=== error writing to path %@, %@", filePath, error.debugDescription);
}
```

The log says

```
=== error writing to path /var/folders/gf/4429772177s9rr234wzlwpz00000gp/T/foobar.dat, 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “foobar.dat” doesn’t exist." 
UserInfo={NSURL=file:///var/folders/gf/4429772177s9rr234wzlwpz00000gp/T/foobar.dat, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x15e0bc20 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}, NSUserStringVariant=Folder}
```

This happens only on my iPhone, not in the simulator. There's GB of free space in the phone. Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**
Added code to check if temp directory exists, and if not, to create it:

```
NSString *dirPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL isDir = NO;
NSError *error = nil;
if (! [fm fileExistsAtPath:dirPath isDirectory:&isDir]) {
    NSLog(@"Directory does not exist at dirPath %@", dirPath);
    BOOL success = [fm createDirectoryAtPath:dirPath
                 withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"=== error: %@", error.debugDescription);
    }
}
```

Again, this error only occurs on my test iPhone 5C, not on the simulator.
This logs

```
Directory does not exist at dirPath /var/folders/gf/4429772177s9rr234wzlwpz00000gp/T/
=== error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “T” in the folder “4429772177s9rr234wzlwpz00000gp”." 
    UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/folders/gf/4429772177s9rr234wzlwpz00000gp/T/, NSUnderlyingError=0x1765cdf0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

The error (513 = bad permissions) makes sense if the last path component ('T') is being treated as a file name, as the error says. So the problem with creating the folder seems similar to that of writing the file, namely that the last path component is being misinterpreted. I also checked that the trailing '/' in the dirPath string is the last character, and it is.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine on an iPhone running iOS 9.1

Comment: Several follow-ups: check if folder which is returned by NSTemporaryDirectory() really exists, check if your path is not ended up with tilde, check if you can perform writing without NSDataWritingAtomic

Comment: I edited the question with the results of the checks suggested by DisableR. However, given those results, I decided not to use NSTemporaryDirectory but to create my own temp folder in the Documents Directory, which works fine.